# exec() not working with unicode characters

Tags: python, encoding

Im trying to execute a .py program from within my python code, but non-ASCII characters behave oddly when printed and dealt with.

module1.py:

```py
test = "áéíóúabcdefgçë"

print(test)
```

Main code:

```py
exec(open("module1.py").read(), globals())
```

I want this to print `áéíóúabcdefgçë` but it instead prints `Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³ÃºabcdefgÃ§Ã«`. This happens with all non-ASCII characters i have tried.

I am using Python 3.7 and Windows 10.

Running module1.py individually does not produce this error, but i want to run the program using exec() or something else that has roughly the same function.

Comment: Which version of Python are you on, and is this a Linux or a Windows system?

Comment: I'm using python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: What happens if you run the `module1.py` script explicitly from the command-line?

Comment: Please add that to the question, so people looking to answer don't have to search in the comments.

Comment: Probably `open('module1.py', encode= "utf-8")` solves your problem

Comment: What happens if your run "`import locale; locale.getpreferredencoding()`" at your Python prompt (without the quotes)?

Comment: A bit late but i get `cp1252` aswell. @jjramsey

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to fix the issue.  Python's `open` is assuming some encoding other than UTF-8.  Changing the main code to the following fixes the issue on my computer (python 3.7 and windows 10):

```
exec(open("module1.py", encoding="utf-8").read(),globals())
```

Thanks @jjramsey for additional information:

According to the [Python documentation for open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), "The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever locale.getpreferredencoding() returns)."

For me, if I run the following check:

```
import locale
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

I get `cp1252`, which is notably not `UTF-8` and so `open()` will cause the issues we have seen in this question, unless we specify the encoding.

Comment: `exec(open("module1.py", 'rb').read(),globals())` worked for me as well, I'm not sure what encoding python thinks it is with the standard open.

Comment: @tgikal According to the [Python documentation for `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), "The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever locale.getpreferredencoding() returns)." For me, leaving off `encoding="utf-8"` works as well, and unsurprisingly, when I run `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, I get `'UTF-8'`.

Comment: @jjramsey Ah, I get `cp1252`

Comment: @jjramsey  Nice! find I'm stealing this to add to the answer

Comment: @tgikal I forgot to add that I did *not* read `module1.py` as binary (no `"rb"` for me). Also, if I use "`encoding = "cp1252"`", I can reproduce the problem that Limerr describes.